# Which package supersedes OptimizeExpression.m from Version 4?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, compile

I used functions from this notebook in some of my very old notebooks.

> OPTIMIZEEXPRESSION.M was in
>   ...Mathematica4.0/ADDONS/STANDARDPACKAGES/NUMERICALMATH/ and it
>   primarily added a function OptimizeExpression for sub-expression
>   optimization of Mathematica expressions.

The package was written by Mark Sofroniou. The keywords of this package name: `Compile`, `CostExpression`, `OptimizeExpression`, `Expression Optimization`, `Polynomial`, `Sub-Expression`, `Syntactic`.

Can this old package still be used? Or is it superseded by a newer one?

Comment: ``Experimental`OptimizeExpression``?

Comment: Since MMA 4 is very long ago for Syntactic [SyntaxLength](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxLength.html) may be the successor.

Answer (score 4):

You can try `` Experimental`OptimizeExpression ``.

```
oexp = Experimental`OptimizeExpression[(3 + 3*a^2 + 
           Sqrt[5 + 6*a + 5*a^2] + a*(4 + Sqrt[5 + 6*a + 5*a^2]))/6]

(*
Experimental`OptimizedExpression[Block[
    {Compile`$1,Compile`$3,Compile`$4,Compile`$5,Compile`$6},
    Compile`$1=a^2;
    Compile`$3=6 a;
    Compile`$4=5 Compile`$1;
    Compile`$5=5+Compile`$3+Compile`$4;
    Compile`$6=Sqrt[Compile`$5];
    1/6 (3+3 Compile`$1+Compile`$6+a (4+Compile`$6))
  ]
]
*)
```

See also [this discussion here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Mar/msg00116.html) from the MathGroup archive.